# Connecting PsychoPy to Biopac MP150

Tags: python, psychopy, psychtoolbox

I want to record the pulse rate with EDA while presenting a music stimuli in psychopy. As the music starts the EDA should start and as the music end the EDA should end.

I am using Biopac MP150 PPGED-R for EDA and Parallel Port for PsychoPy with AcqKnowledge 4.3 Software for MP150.

When I tried connecting, I got an error

```
p_port = parallel.ParallelPort(address=u'0x0378')

int((self.port,Inp32(self.base + 0x402) & ~BYTEMODEMASK) (1<<5)) )

**WindowsError: exception: privileged instruction**
```

I am still trying to figure out the solution for same.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really just about python accessing the parallel port (it isn't about PsychoPy, Biopac or psychtoolbox).

There were several answers to the same question here:
[Python Access Parallel Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945160/python-access-parallel-port)

Maybe one of those can help you?